# AngularJS: Passing into a directive link function an attribute AND the entire scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that has an attirbute, it looks like this:

```
<directive config="myConfig"></directive>
```

This is my directives code:

```
app.directive("directive", ["$compile", ($compile) => {
    return {
      scope: {"config":"="},
      template: "<div></div>",
      link: function(s,e,a) {
        // I want my scope here so I could use $compile to compile a directive into it
        // ('it' being the scope the directive lives in).
        // Yet I also want the config variable so I could $watch it.
      }
    }
});
```

As shown, I want the config variable and the entire scope, is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use isolated scope then. just add `config` to the parent scope, and the directive `directive` could watch it since it is on the same scope.
your new directive (the one you want to compile) could have an isolated scope.